# How to prove that $ns^{n-1}$ is bounded for all $n \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis

> If $0 < s < 1$, then prove that $ns^{n-1}$ is bounded for all $n \geq 1$.

---

The proof is simple with the ratio test for the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ns^{n-1}$. Since the series converges, then the sequence of partial sum converges, and thus each term is bounded.

**Question:**
**Is there a more general way to do this?**
For example, if I know that $f(x)$ grows asymptotically slower than $g(x)$, is there a way to show that for some a>0, $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is bounded when $x>a$? I can see making an appeal to limits and showing that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{n}{(\frac{1}{s})^n-1} \rightarrow 0$ using L'Hopital's rule, but how do I translate this fact about limits into a statement that $\exists M > 0$ such that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < M$ to show boundedness?

Comment: Show the derivative has exactly one real root. Then there is a unique maximum and it's clearly non-negative.

Comment: You have to do a bit more.  $1$ grows slower than $x$ as $x\to\infty$, but it's not true that $1/x$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$

Comment: @saulspatz I've added an additional condition.

Comment: It is certainly a true fact that if $h(x)$ is continuous on $[a,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} h(x) = 0$, then $h(x)$ is bounded on $[a,\infty)$. This can be applied to $h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ if that quotient is continuous.

Comment: Oh yes, it's a straightforward application of the definition of limits at infinity, silly me. Thank you.